# Web Push Notification working on Android but not on IOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, safari, service-worker, web-push

I am trying to send push notifications from a web app to mobile phone using this code.

```
function notify(mess) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
  Notification.requestPermission(function (result) {
    if (result === 'granted') {
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) {
        registration.showNotification('Valet Pra', {
          body: mess,
          icon: './WebsiteLogo.png',
          vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
          tag: 'vibration-sample',
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

The sw.js file is empty.

I get the notifications on my android phone using chrome browser.

However, when I try the same on IOS (Safari and Chrome) in iPhone, the notifications are not created.

Kindly, help me out here. I'm open to try out any other method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome for ios uses safari webkit. So you must watch webkit development status on Notification api:

https://webkit.org/status/

you can support this feature request:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182566

This still not working on ios (check safari ios column) :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#browser_compatibility

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification#browser_compatibility